# How to make automatic load popover after pages loaded without using click, hover, focus?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap3 and I want to create popover to show in on pages or document has loaded then show popover on the each html element **without** using **hover**,**click**, **focus** But it worn't work as what I want.

***And How can I create disable button on popover when popover pop up after pages loaded which easy for me click hide pop up back?***

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".popover-examples a").popover({
            placement:'auto',
            title : 'a',
            animation:true, 
            trigger:'hover',
            content:'a',
//                  delay: { show: 0, hide: 5000000 },
            container:'body',
            viewport:'#viewport',
            template:'<div class="popover"><div class="arrows"></div><input type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm hide-popover" value="Hide"><h3 class="popover-titles">popver-title</h3><div class="popover-contents">contina;lkjdfaksljdf;lajsjdf;asdjfaldsf</div></div>',
            });
     });

      $(".hide-popover").click(function(){
            $("button.popover-examples").popover('hide');
     }); 
</script>
```

here is html element

```
<td  class="popover-examples">
     <a data-toggle="popover"  href="<?php echo base_url('invoice/edit');?>">
         Received Date
     </a>
</td>
```

what should I correct with those above code?
Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your popover setting, the trigger is on hover.
You can change it to "manual", and trigger it using:

```
$(".popover-examples a").popover("show");
```

Comment: Yes It is working but How can I using click to disable it bake because I add destroy to this option
template:'<div class="popover"><div class="arrows"></div> <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger destroy-popover" value="Hide"><h3 class="popover-titles">popver-title</h3><div class="popover-contents">contina;lkjdfaksljdf;lajsjdf;asdjfaldsf</div></div>',
it should be work or not if it not work how can I do

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. You want to have another button, and once it's clicked, it will disable the popover? disabling here means hiding the popover right?

Comment: Yes that right I mean after popover show and than I create one button on popover to click for hiding it

Comment: Here's jsfiddle for closing button inside popover: http://jsfiddle.net/bmvo4mLs/ , you need to set html:true in popover setting also, to let button rendered correctly